# Ruby - decrease integers from params one by one and loop with those

Tags: ruby, loops

A palindromic number reads the same both ways. The largest palindrome made from the product of two *2-digit* numbers is `9009 = 91 × 99`.

Find the largest palindrome made from the product of two *3-digit* numbers.
I am very new to Ruby and coding, so struggling with this one quite a while. Here is what I have:

```
def biggest(num, num2)
  total = num * num2
  x = total.to_s.split('')

  until x[0] == x[-1] && x[1] == x[-2] && x[2] == x[-3]
    num = num - 1
    num2 = num2 - 1
    total = num * num2
    x = total.to_s.split('')
  end

  return x
end

p biggest(999, 999)
```

Problem is that this decreases both params at the same time and gives a wrong answer. I think I should decrease only one number at a time: `999 - 1 * 999`, and if not meets condition, decrease other: `999 - 1 * 999 - 1`. And keep looping like this until true.

I know this is not the best approach to this method. It I think it is even wrong from mathematical aspect, but I am just learning, so I kindly ask to give me some insights how this code could be improved. Any optional approaches are very welcome but most important for me is how to fix my mistakes made here.

Comment: you need a double (nested) loop. you should also try to separate the logic for looping the numbers and the logic to check whether a number is a palindrome. also, for looping, use ranges or `Integer#downto` method instead of `while` or `until`.

Comment: thanks, I will try that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you found out yourself, the main reason why your implementation doesn't work is because you decrement both `num` and `num2` thus iterating over `[i, i]` pairs rather than `[i, j]`.

Your second issue is that even if you did decrement them one after the other, your `until` still assumes that the solution must be a `[n0, m0]` pair, where `max(n0, m0) >= max(ni, mj)`, for `∀ni, mj: ni ∈ 100..999, mj ∈ 100..999 and ni * mj is palindrome`.

Your third problem is stylistic - Ruby is a higher level language, yet you do comparison of characters manually. Here is a possible solution:

```
max = 0

100.upto(999) do |x|
  x.upto(999) do |y|
    product = x * y
    max = product if product > max and product.to_s.reverse.to_i == product
  end
end

max
```

(Note that the second index starting from `x` rather than `100` is just an optimization)

Comment: oh, that is crazy. Pretty neat solution. I am vary amazed. Thanks!